# how to check wether listview footer is scrolled in the screen

Tags: android, listview, scroll, footer

Having a ListView, and added a footer view to it.

```
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

So this footer could be scrolled in and out.
I'm wondering if there is simple way to check whether the footerView is scrolled in the screen's viewport. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getLastVisiblePosition()` on your listView. This position should include all headers and footers.